# Adding output from a batch file called by internal program to the project build logs

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a project in CCNet and the executable needs to run a batch file. Is there a way of extracting the output from the batch file so it can be picked up by the build log? As all I've been able to get back so far has been a return code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try piping the output of the batch file to a log file and then then use a [file merge task](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/File%20Merge%20Task.html) to merge the contents into the build log.